# Google oauth prompts for user consent everytime

Tags: php, google-oauth

I am trying to put google login to my website using the userinfo example code from google-php-client. And now everytime i the same user tries to login it prompts at consent screen. Also If the token expires if gives error the next time the user logs in. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have the following parameters in the request URL:

- display=prompt
- prompt=force

Either of these values will force the user to re-consent each time.

Comment: HI, approval_prompt=auto is what i have. Still it asks for consent. Is I Also tried using OpenId Oauth, There i found that when only openid is placed in scope the google consent prompt doesnt appear second time. But when the scope contains user_basic information and email it asks for consent screen again and again. Can it be because of scope data? How do i solve this?

Comment: @FarazAzhar : i found no solution to it. I took a work around which fetched the openid for the user and checks if the openid for that user is already registered, if not registered store the openid and asked for google authentication else if openid exists in db then directly log in the user.